# Gitlab-runner without Docker

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've installed gitlab-runner on ubuntu 16.04

I've set Executor=shell

My project is hosted on gitlab.com with a very simple yaml config file :

```
dev:
 script:
 - pwd
```

I am **not** willing to user Docker for the moment

**Why is the job's log is mentioning docker ?**

> Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
>
> Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
>
> Using docker image ... for ruby:2.5 ...

**Why is it mentioning a path that does not exist when executing pwd ?**

```
$ pwd
/builds/my_gitlab_name/my_project_name
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information to debug your problem.  Are you sure that your runner rather than a shared runner is being used?

Comment: I believe you are right. In the right pane of the job log it shows : Runner: shared-runners-manager-3.gitlab.com. I Will try to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sam Hartman is right my runner was not the one responsible for the job's log.

I had to deactivate Shared Runners in order to see my runner running.

If you need to do this simply go to

Settings -> CI / CD -> expand Runners -> and on the right pane names Shared runners clic on "Disable Shared Runner" for this project

Comment: uff. what if I want to run jobs on both because I need support different CPU architectures?