# Getting docker error while using shell gitlab-runner ERRO[0000]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello I got this error at the installation,
when I use the command "gitlab-runner run" or "gitlab-runner start":

```
ERRO[0000] Docker executor: prebuilt image helpers will be loaded from /var/lib/gitlab-runner
```

The strange thing about it is, I using a shell runner.
I also tried on another server with no problems.
Even I tried it with a docker build and without.

I installed via

```
apt install gitlab-runner
```

Also I upgraded it and updated also. Rebuild the server (digitalocean droplet Ubuntu20.04)) and jep ... dont know what is going on.

Here also some output og the gitlab-runner:

```
root@Server:~# gitlab-runner verify
ERRO[0000] Docker executor: prebuilt image helpers will be loaded from /var/lib/gitlab-runner.
Running in system-mode.

Verifying runner... is alive                        runner=xVNzfox5

root@Server:~# gitlab-runner list
ERRO[0000] Docker executor: prebuilt image helpers will be loaded from /var/lib/gitlab-runner.
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
test                                                Executor=shell Token=JustAToken
URL=https://gitlab.com/
```

All I found about this error was about docker runner, but like I said I use a shell runner.

Thanks if someone can help.

Answer (score 13):

Using this command `apt-cache policy gitlab-runner`, you will notice that only version 11.2.0 of `gitlab-runner` is available on the repositories, which is not [supported](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4773) by Gitlab.

Follow the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) to install the latest version 14.2.0.

```
$ sudo curl -L --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64"
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
$ sudo useradd --comment 'GitLab Runner' --create-home gitlab-runner --shell /bin/bash
$ # Optional sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service
$ sudo gitlab-runner install --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since the last update of gitlab-cc.

Found this related post which helped:

[Gitlab-runner without Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304594/gitlab-runner-without-docker?rq=1)

So just disable shared runners (until someone fixes this issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with gitlab-runner version 13.x.

Updating to version 14.2.0 solved the problem.

Comment: To update, if you can't update manually to 14.x (such as with raspberry pi), go to https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/index.html and pick the correct package. For raspberry pi you want to do `curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_armhf.deb"` followed by `sudo dpkg -i gitlab-runner_armhf.deb`